# Extend IOBluetoothHostController in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, extend

I would like to create class for managing (discovering, connecting) bluetooth classic devices for OS X (something like **CBCentralManager** for BLE). I need to know host controller power state so I decided to extend **IOBluetoothHostController** (and use **powerState** property from it). I have to implement **defaultController** class method in a subclass.

```
@interface IOBCentralManager : IOBluetoothHostController {}  
+ (IOBCentralManager *)defaultController;  
@end

@implementation IOBCentralManager  
+ (IOBCentralManager *)defaultController  
{  
    return (IOBCentralManager *)[super defaultController];  
}  
@end
```

and then

```
IOBCentralManager *hci = [IOBCentralManager defaultController];
switch (hci.powerState) {
...
}
```

Is it good idea? Would You suggest better solution?